# GIT: ignore *.js only if *.coffee is present in the same directory

Tags: git

I want to ignore only those *.js file that have their *.coffee counterpart, other *.js files must be included. How can I achieve this without entering each file to .gitignore?

Answer (score 0):

I think with .gitignore you cannot do that.

You can create a script, (bash? php?) for add in each folder with a file .coffee a .gitignore with the same name of the directory in.

If you have a list of folder with js, just loop them, check if a file .coffee is present, if yes, create .gitignore, if no delete .gitignore...

And just before commit, run your script ;)